# unable to use scss in storybook in monorepo vue app - module build error lang="scss"

Tags: javascript, sass, loader, storybook, monorepo

I am adding storybook in an existing monorepo and keep getting error when trying to add scss via `<style lang="scss">`:

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
```

This is the outline of monorepo structure:

```
package.json
.storybook
  |_ main.js
  |_ preview.js
client
  |_package.json
  |_ src
    |_components
    |_styles
    |_stories
```

The relevant root package.json looks like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn workspaces foreach run build",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^6.3.7",
    "@types/mdx-js__react": "^1",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.5.0"
  }
```

Here is my .storybook/main.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../client/src/stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../client/src/stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-scss"
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
  config.module.rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    }
  );

    return config;
  },
}
```

In my vue components, trying to use `<style lang="scss">` throws the above error. I thought scss would be handled by the changes made in .storybook/main.js, but it's not working, and I'm wondering if it has something to do with the monorepo and two package.json, or if it is something else.

Comment: Can you include your webpack version?

Comment: Storybook uses its own webpack under the hood, I'll have to research what version they are using.

Comment: It looks like there is a way to opt in for webpack version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the package.json you've provided, you may be encountering this bug:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/923

In short, using Vue 3 with `sass-loader v11.0.0` or higher without Webpack v5 leads to this error. An interim solution may be to install a known-compatible version of `sass-loader`:

```sh
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@10.1.1
```

Or, if using yarn:

```sh
yarn add --save-dev sass-loader@10.1.1
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the storybook's webpack to version 5 as shown here solved the issue:
https://gist.github.com/shilman/8856ea1786dcd247139b47b270912324#upgrade